# How do I compress or compact encrypted virtualbox disk image

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization

As I have created a Debian VM inside VirtualBox by encrypting their partition. So that the OS must be running in an encrypted partition. Although while creating a disk image(VHD), I had given for Dynamic allocation, but after OS installation it looks the disk image was consuming the entire disk space. Now the image size is 20GB. Is it possible for us to compress or compact it to some smaller sizes. I saw the documentations to compact the disk image in Virtual Box, but I may need to know whether we can do the same for encrypted disk image.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Superuser would be more appropriate for this question.  http://superuser.com

Comment: this might help, but generally it's complicated: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14977

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type of encryption being used. Since you're using Debian I assume you're using LUKS, which is inflexible.  The space has to be pre-allocated and therefore the image will utilise the full space allocated to it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a way to do it, but too complex to do it.

Each time you need/want to compact it you need to do some steps carefully.

1. (Maybe this is not really need it, try first without this) Blank with zeros all free space inside 'clear' mounted partitions, so free space is zeroed in 'clear', it will not be zeroed in 'encrypted' view point, since encryption will encrypt such zeros.
2. Shutdown the machine and boot with a LiveCD iso that let you mount the virtual hdd you are using and a new 'dynamic' and 'empty' one.
3. Set the partition scheme and encription identically on the new one, but ensure encription will not do the 'fill' part, so it does not write all sectors... this is the top most important part... this way the new virtual disk is smalll in size, but encypted by you LUKs, etc.
4. At this point, only scheme and encryption is on the new 'small' one, now is time to mount both enctypted... the old and the new, so they can see in 'plain' at the same time.
5. Again this is very important, clone form the old 'plain' to the new 'plain' only sectors that have data (most tools to clone partitions does that).

As i say... the top most important thing (to get a smaller virtual HDD) is:

- Create a new virtual dynamic disk empty
- Partition it and Encrypt it without writting all sectors; so omit the dd with random data prior to do the encryption or else the dynamic file will grow to max), also omit the fill empty space, that again will grow the virtual disk to max
- Clone the partitions from the plain view (mounted and de-crypted on fly), so the clone tool will only write data areas of files, etc, but not free space.

There is a small part that will not be able to be reduced... files inside encrypted partitions that have full clusters fill with zeros (hope you do not have any of thoose)... the cause is that such space (when no encryption, as is all zeros, the normal compat see the full cluster is zero so it does not need such space; but when it is encrypted, such cluster is not all zero inside the real virtaul disk file, so the compact method can not reduce it).

The idea behind all is:

- When encryption is on... to get the smallest virtual disk size, start with a dynamic and empty one and write as less as possible clusters on it when cloning the previous one.

As said, it is too much work... and time to time, each write occurs it will start growing and growing again.

My best personal recomendation is, get a 'BIG' and 'FAST' disk and use a fixed virtual disk... if i read well and your disk is only 20GiB... you gain in speed a lot for having it fixed and not dynamic and will not get worried about 'fragmentation' etc.

Remember if you use a USB for it, get one able to write at 30MiB/s (if only have USB 2.0 ports), if you are lucky (like me) and have at least one USB 3 port (better if it is a USB 3.1 Gen 2 Type C) seach for a 2.5 inch HDD 500GiB Sata III (with write speed greater than 100MiB/s, it is really cheap, less than 25 euros) and a Sata III to USB 3.1 Gen 2 Type C enclosure (also cheap, some are under 15 euros)... and avoid having to 'reduce', 'clone' etc.

I have 10 virtual machines on a 500GiB (with more than 50% free space), each is 20GiB in size (with Windows system inside them taking near 16BiG) and VeraCrypt encryption... so i am on the quite near case to you... i opted to use a USB 3.1 gen 2 Type C enclosure to hold all the fixed size VDI files... my experience is that encrypted fixed size fly if compared to non encrypted dynamic size.

Of course, ensure you do the needed test (when encryption takes place), i mean... test virtual HDD speed with no encryption, then test encryption algorithms on ram... and choose a method that is faster than 1.6 times the speed of the disk... so encription will not be a bottle neck... else you can have a really bad speed caused by encryption.

Also think on this, how much cores you show to the guest? that will make encryption speed very different... but also think the worst case... how much CPU will use the non encryption threads on that guest?

Just as an example... if inside the guest you are doing LZMA2 compression (or video transcoding H.264 for example) etc... the free CPU for encryption is very low... so encryption will slow down things a lot... sample cases also do much I/O to disks, so encrypt/decrypt a lot per second is needed.

Maybe a better aproach... would be... encrypt the 'container' not the 'system'... in other words... encrypt where the VDI files are stored, not the whole guest system... create a container per VDI if want different phrase passwords, etc. That way the VDI can also be dynamic and be compacted, etc.

Of course, i would be of more help if you told what encryption scheme (without details) are using.

This makes a really great difference in possible answers:

- Are you encrypting system partition with any tool that runs on guest? Then use the 'clone' only used clusters trick
- Are you encrypting but setting the VDI encryption property on? Maybe VirtualBox console will help to compat them
- Are you encrypting the container where VDI is stored? I am quite sure this is not your case, since in such case compact can be done as normal, VDI is not encrypted at all, neither anything iside it.

I talk about VDI... same applies to the rest formats, VHD, VHDx, etc.

Remember... if encription is done on guest and still want to reduce (compact) the virtua hdd file... start with a new dynamic one, put partition scheme, encryption but without filling all the disk... at this point virtual disk file size must not be great, just a few megabytes... then clone form the old to the new one all used clusters, but not the not used ones.

Advise: Prepare to repeat the 'compact' by 'cloning' a few times per 100 hours of intense use of the guest... if gain is less than 50% it does not compensate the effort... then the best can be done is use fixed size.

Special note: With Fixed size the access speed is much more than with dynamic size... having a dynamic size with 100% size as if it where fixed is a big lost in speed... how much? you must do the test in your machine, depends a lot on CPU, I/O speed (input/ouptup operations per second) of storage you have and also on transfer speed (MiB/s), and other factors... so best do some test.

Since you are talking about 20GiB... better do the test of fixed size... i am quite sure you will enjoy it a lot.

Other thing would be talking about 500GiB system partition with only 10% fill... since space gain could be 450GiB, it is wellcome to do the clone method to compact it, that is why i say how to do such... for such people and your you, and for any one.

P.D.: If someone does not know how to do something, that does not mean it is not possible, and if someone say something is not possible, better for that person explain the demostration or be prepeared to be called an idiot; technology improves a lot time to time, knowledge a lot more.